# How to get the command & arguments that was executed in shell with python

Tags: python, bash, argv, sys

I am running a command in aws-cli to get the logs and i need to perform some opertaion in python with the output of this command.

I am doing something like this:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name "something" --log-stream-names my-log-stream --filter-pattern "status=FAIL" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin))"
```

The above command gets the aws logs and runs the python code snippet to print the json returned.

I want to access the `log-group-name` and `log-stream-name` i.e "something" & "my-log-stream" (in this case) in my python code snippet. I am not sure how this can be done.

I have tried using `sys.argv` but it returns me the arguments passed in the python command i.e `['-c']` and not the aws command.

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done because these are arguments _to a different command_, not Python. You could execute the whole command from within Python using the `subprocess` module

Comment: Actually that was the second option that i have thoudh of but i would have to make a lot of changes in my bash script. Just wanted to know if it was doable this way.

Comment: @Mohan: A general practice in programming is that, if you need one piece of information in two places, you bind it to a variable and use the variable in every place. It makes maintenance easier. In your case, you could use environment variables to hold the log group and the log stream, and use these variables in both your aws command and within Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how pipe works. It just sends the output of the command to the next command. You could set the `log-group-name` and `log-stream-name` as environment variables

```
export LGN=something
...
```

and then access it in python with `os.environ["LGN"]` ... similar to this

```
export LGN="my-log-group"; <your code here> | python3 -c "import os; print(os.environ['LGN'])"
```